# Installing Ubuntu Without USB

Tags: boot

Trying to install UBUNTU  on a laptop.
I created a boot USB which worked fine on my desktop.
I cannot access the BIOS on the laptop and therefore can't change the boot sequence

Tried burning to DVD with isoburner, it gets to the purple ubuntu screen and stops on " Scanning disk for index files "

Tried Unetbootin which didn't work either.

Comment: This site supports Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu, not generic Linux.  Assuming it was Ubuntu (or official flavor of Ubuntu), did you use the 'check disc for defects' option to verify download, or validate your write-to-DVD?

Comment: Sorry dude i mean ubuntu. Just edited the post.
I tried ISO Burner and the burner in windows. and yes i verified the contents after burning

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? 32 or 64 bits? Please tell us the brand name and model of the laptop. -- Cloning is a reliable method to create a USB boot drive. Please try with the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator or [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/) (in Ubuntu in the desktop computer) or [Win32 Disk Imager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb) in Windows.

Comment: 64 bit
Ok. I think the USB i used to transfer the file over to my laptop was corrupt as I disconnected it before it said it was safe to remove.
So I downloaded 18.04 instead of 19.4, burned to DVD and now it's installing ! hopefully it works ok

Comment: I think you found the problem. Good luck with 18.04 LTS :-)

Answer (score 0):

The USB i used to transfer the file over to my laptop was corrupt as I disconnected it before it said it was safe to remove. So I downloaded 18.04 instead of 19.4, burned to DVD and now it's installing